# How to group consecutive date on conditions

Tags: mysql, psql

i want group of consecutive date on some condition basis

my query is

```
WITH
  dates(date) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(leave_date AS DATE),t.employee_id,up.display_value
    FROM hrms.t_employee_leave_request t left join hrms.t_lookup up on up.id=t.leave_status_id
  )
,
  groups AS (
    select
    employee_id,display_value,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS rn,
      date((date - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) * interval '1 day')) as grp,
      date
    FROM dates
  )
  SELECT
  employee_id,display_value,
  COUNT(*) AS consecutiveDates,
  MIN(date) AS minDate,
  MAX(date) AS maxDate
FROM groups
GROUP BY employee_id,grp,display_value
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 desc;
```

which will return table result as

### |empid  | action                |days |fromdate    |todate       |

### |1022   |PendingApproval  | 3   | 2018-03-19 |   2018-03-22|

### |1022   |Approved         |1    | 2018-03-20 |   2018-03-20|

but i want the data as given below

### |empid  | action                |days |fromdate    |todate       |

### |1022   |PendingApproval  | 1   | 2018-03-19 |   2018-03-19|

### |1022   |PendingApproval  | 2   | 2018-03-21 |   2018-03-22|

### |1022   |Approved         |1    | 2018-03-20 |   2018-03-20|

please help me to solve

Comment: WITH/Common table expression is not available in mysql until version 8+ are on version 8+?

Comment: i am using psql